# Maximise entropy of random sample of random distribution

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, information-theory, entropy

> Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be positive discrete r.v.s such that $p^j_k = \mathbb{P}(X_j=k)$. Let $N \in \{ 1, ..., n\}$ be a discrete r.v. with pmf $a_j=\mathbb{P}(N=j)$. Then $X_N$ is the random variable chosen by sampling a random $p^j$ distribution according to $a_j$.
>
> Calculate $H(N, X_N)$ and, for $p^j_k$ fixed, find its maximum value and the value of $a_1, ..., a_n$ which achieves it.

I believe $$ H(N,X_N)=-\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_jp^j_k\log(a_jp^j_k)$$

I would guess that this is maximised by $$a_j=\frac{H(X_j)}{\sum_{j=1}^nH(X_j)}$$ simply because it seems like giving a higher probability to the r.v.s with more entropy would maximise the entropy. How can I prove (or disprove) this, preferably using Lagrange multipliers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be stated as:

$$\max_{a\in K} -\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_j p_{jk}\log(a_j p_{jk})$$

where $K=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\ge 0\,\mid\,a_1+\ldots+a_n=1\}$. This is a very favorable case of convex programming (objective is concave, constraints are affine) so for example in that case [KKT conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) are necessary and sufficient conditions for optimality. So if we consider:

$$\begin{align} f(a)&=-\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_j p_{jk}\log(a_j p_{jk})\\
g_i(a)&=-a_i\\
h(a)&=a_1+\ldots+a_n-1\end{align}$$

Notice that:

$$\begin{align}\nabla f(a)&=(-1-\log a_j+H(X_j))^T_{1\le j\le n}\\
\nabla g_i(a)&=-e_i\\
\nabla h(a)&=(1,\ldots,1)^T
\end{align}$$

Then at optimal $a^*$:

- *Stationary condition*: $-1-\log a^*_j+H(X_j)-\mu_j-\lambda=0$ for all $j$
- *Primal feasability*: $a^*_j\ge 0$ for all $j$ and $a^*_1+\ldots +a^*_n=1$
- *Dual feasability*: $\mu_j\ge 0$ for all $j$
- *Complementary slackness*: $\mu_j a^*_j=0$ for all $j$

The only way all these conditions are simultaneous satisfied is when $a^*_j=Ce^{H(X_j)}$ (for some constant $C$), so in the end:

$$a^*_j=\frac{e^{H(X_j)}}{\sum_{j=1}^n e^{H(X_j)}}$$

is the optimal solution. You can get to the same result using Lagrange multipliers but you probably need to handle manually what happens at the boundary.